# cannot install django with python of macos

Tags: python, django, macos

I just cannot install django on my mac :/

Here:
brew uninstall python, brew install python, pip install django, python, import django

```
nma-2:~ nikolaialeksandrenko$ brew uninstall python
Error: No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/python
nma-2:~ nikolaialeksandrenko$ brew install python
Warning: You have not agreed to the Xcode license.
Builds will fail! Agree to the license by opening Xcode.app or running:
    xcodebuild -license
==> Downloading http://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.4/Python-2.7.4.tar.bz2
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/python-2.7.4.tar.bz2
==> ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.4 --enable-ipv6 --datarootdir=/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.4/share --datadir=/usr/local/Cellar
==> make
==> make install PYTHONAPPSDIR=/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.4
==> make frameworkinstallextras PYTHONAPPSDIR=/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.4/share/python
==> Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/d/distribute/distribute-0.6.38.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/distribute-0.6.38.tar.gz
==> /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.4/bin/python -s setup.py --no-user-cfg install --force --verbose --install-lib=/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.4/Frame
==> Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/pip/pip-1.3.1.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/pip-1.3.1.tar.gz
==> /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.4/bin/python -s setup.py --no-user-cfg install --force --verbose --install-lib=/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.4/Frame
==> Caveats
Homebrew's Python framework
  /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.4/Frameworks/Python.framework

Python demo
  /usr/local/share/python/Extras

Distribute and Pip have been installed. To update them
  pip install --upgrade distribute
  pip install --upgrade pip

To symlink "Idle" and the "Python Launcher" to ~/Applications
  `brew linkapps`

You can install Python packages with (the outdated easy_install or)
  `pip install <your_favorite_package>`

They will install into the site-package directory
  /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages

Executable python scripts will be put in:
  /usr/local/share/python
so you may want to put "/usr/local/share/python" in your PATH, too.

See: https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/Homebrew-and-Python
==> Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.4: 5195 files, 80M, built in 102 seconds
nma-2:~ nikolaialeksandrenko$ brew link python
Warning: Already linked: /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.4
To relink: brew unlink python && brew link python
nma-2:~ nikolaialeksandrenko$ pip install Django
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): Django in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Cleaning up...
nma-2:~ nikolaialeksandrenko$ python
Python 2.7.2 (default, Oct 11 2012, 20:14:37) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple Clang 4.0 (tags/Apple/clang-418.0.60)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import django
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named django
>>> import Django
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named Django
>>>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download Django [here](https://www.djangoproject.com/m/releases/1.5/Django-1.5.4.tar.gz). The default steps to install django on macos can be found [here](https://www.djangoproject.com/download/).

```
tar xzvf Django-1.5.4.tar.gz
cd Django-1.5.4
sudo python setup.py install
```

Answer (score 0):

The linking is not working. The one you link to (or attempt to link to) is python 2.7.4, yet when you run `python` it clearly shows "Python 2.7.2".

Try running this inside python:

```
import site; site.getsitepackages()
```

It should show you the location of the `site-packages` directories associated with the python version you are running. Another thing to try is just running `which python` to see which executable you are actually calling.

If it turns out to be incorrect (compare it with the django install directory), you should just manually add the other python directory to your path. Put this in your `.profile` file in your home directory:

```
PATH="/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.4/bin/:$PATH"
```

This makes sure that the newly installed Homebrew-specific python is the one executed when you run it without any path - this should hopefully match the executable that `pip` is using.